# How can i implement touch ripple for my Gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, material-design

I want to implement Surface Reaction section of this webpage helps.

[Google material design guide](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-surface-reaction).But i do not can implement this.

How can i implement this? Thank you.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgTJg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ripple.xml` in your drawable folder with the following code.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                      android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
 </ripple>
```

And then set this as your background for the GridView items using

```
android:background="@drawable/ripple"
```

Comment: thanks for your code but i added this to my xml like this <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1880dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple" > and error occur "error inflating android.widget.gridview".

Comment: You're supposed to add that code in to your **GridView items**, not the GridView itself. Add it to the images that you are using in the GridView adapter class layout.

Comment: .can you please help me where i put the code. as you know android:background="@drawable/ripple" is for xml file but for what element i must use this code. i used public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
                               
                               
                               arg1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple); but app is force closing.

Comment: You must be using an adapter for your GridView right? Can you post the code of the adapter's `getView()` method?

Comment: Thats the wrong place to put the code. You are supposed to put the code in your android xml file of the layout that is used in your `getView()` of the GridViews adapter class

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a while searching for an answer to this myself, but once I figured it out, it turns out it was actually pretty simple.

Instead of trying to add the ripple to each individual view in the adapter, you can just add it at the GridView level like this:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"

    ...

    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/your_ripple_drawable"/>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thank you. but this is occur when i add your code to my gridview http://s3.picofile.com/file/8191799434/device_2015_06_09_123240.png

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing your code, but I'm guessing you're trying to use a ripple in an earlier version of Android. You'll need to put your ripple code in a -v21 folder and have an alternative drawable to fall back on for previous Android versions.

Comment: Here's an example, just in case you need it: https://gist.github.com/AnderWeb/9672f5d81017429fd5fd

Comment: I use android 4.4 kitkat

Comment: Ripples were added in API 21 (Lollipop), so KitKat is not new enough. You'll need to run it on an emulator to actually use the ripple effect.

Comment: you say i can not use it in kitkat?

Comment: Yes. Lollipop and above only. You'll have to provide a fallback drawable for pre-v21 versions of Android, as shown in the gist I posted earlier.

Comment: There are also some 3rd party libraries you can try that claim to provide backward compatibility for ripples, but since I've never used any of them, I couldn't recommend one.

Comment: I want if user has lollipop then he can to use this ripple. how can i do that?

Comment: like this: gist.github.com/AnderWeb/9672f5d81017429fd5fd